# Java - How to get the bit number (index) from a given value?

Tags: java

I have one single number which is a guaranteed power of two (1,2,4,8,16,...etc).
How can I get the "bit index" from this number?

Say, I get the number "8" -> The answer I seek is "3" (bit#3)

```
 1 -> 0
 2 -> 1
 4 -> 2
 8 -> 3
16 -> 4
32 -> 5
..etc...
```

Of course I can build an array or a dictionary (the key being the number, the value the bit#) of... say 16 indices to get from the value to the bit#,

I can also do a

```
int i = 0, counter = 1;
while (counter != needed_value) {
    counter *= 2;
    i++;
}
// now "i" contains my bit#
```

but is there a... more fancy way?

Comment: I think you're just looking for the base 2 logarithm of that number... right?

Comment: ...maybe?... **looks a bit unsure around** what would that mean?

Answer (score 3):

Nothing fancy, just what the `java.lang.Integer` class provides (although the implementation is somewhat fancy):

```
int lowestOneBit = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(needed_value);
```

Comment: That looks good - Thank you very much - wasn't aware of this! and yes... looking at the implementation ... whow :)

Comment: @Grisgram the `Integer` class has several such helpful gems - look at `highestOneBit()`, `lowestOneBit()`, `bitCount()`, `reverse()`, `reverseBytes()`

Comment: Thanks - yes I see - there are interesting things (reverseBytes!) that can help greatly

Answer (score 3):

When *2^x = y* then *log<sub>2</sub>(y) = x*. You know *y*, so the solution is:

```java
Math.log(y) / Math.log(2)
```

This is because *log<sub>b</sub>(a) = log(a) / log(b)*.

Answer (score 0):

You can just find first significant bit in integer:

```
public static Optional<Integer> getFirstSignificantBit(int src) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        if ((src & 1) == 1) {
            return Optional.of(i);
        }
        src >>= 1;
    }

    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about recursive!

```
  private static int bitIndex(int n) {
        if (n <= 1)
            return 0;
        return 1 + bitIndex(n/2);
    }
```